# what script to use for automating http requests with object ids?

Tags: python, scripting, httprequest, url-routing, httpresponse

I have a list of IDs in a file. I need to access a website, where I need to extract ids from file and insert these ids in URL for referencing objects and record the response for each http request. how can I automate this using scripts and what type of scripts/technology I need to use? I am a beginner

Comment: You should try selenium.

Comment: I think Django can help you and it is very easy to solve your issue with python and django

Comment: @VikasDamodar without django can i do only in python ?

Comment: yes there is one option with `beautifulsoup`. But it depends on your requirements . Because it only returns website contents .Its a type of web scraping .